# How to swap Escape and Caps Lock?

Tags: linux, vim, arch-linux

I am using Archlinux. When I program , I like to swap the Escape and Caps Lock.

I know that gnome can do this job. But Gnome 3.6.2 in the Archlinux can not find this.

So i use the xmodmap and create a file : ~/.xmodmap

```
  clear Lock
  keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
  keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
  add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

when i run:

```
  xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

it works well.

But it can not work automatic when i login the gnome, even though i add `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` to `~/.xprofile`.

Am I doing something wrong ? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7):

<del>Avoid using xmodmap as its another daemon that has to run.</del> Unless touching other keys, ise the simpler and still Xorg upstream `setxkbmap`, which can be found in the `extra/xorg-setxkbmap` package.

See [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/566871/how-to-map-the-caps-lock-key-to-escape-key-in-archlinux/568573#568573) for how to automatically have this start when you start GNOME, but use the `caps:swapescape` option instead. For example, if you are using `startx` and `~/.xinitrc`, add the following to it:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

Comment: `xmodmap` is not a daemon: it only modifies keymap and then completely exits.

Comment: Point. Fixing that.

Answer (score 4):

The file you should create is `~/.Xmodmap` with the capital X. 
Depending on which login manager (gdm, xdm, etc...) you use the `~/.Xmodmap` should be automatically loaded, if this isn't happing, as it seems in your question, you can edit your `~/.xsession` and `~/.xinitrc` files and add these line to force loading your `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
 [ -f ~/.Xmodmap ] && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create a file with name `~/.Xmodmap` (note the big X). As I see in `/etc/gdm/Xsession` gdm loads `~/.Xmodmap` if it exists so you don't need `~/.xprofile` or similar hack :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following command into your `.bashrc` file

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
```

For example I keep the following line in my .bashrc file

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

which  adds an extra escape instead of Caps Lock.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solutions works under X11.

## GNOME On Wayland

If you have GNOME on Wayland, you can use this to swap your Esc with Caps Lock key:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:swapescape']"
```

## Plasma On Wayland

If you have Plasma (KDE) on Wayland, please go to System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced, and on the second "Caps Lock behavior" item, check "Swap Esc and Caps Lock".

This has been tested on Plasma 5.27.

[image]

Comment: how do you undo this?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"`