# How to map the Caps Lock key to Escape key in Arch Linux

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, keymap, xmodmap

My OS is Arch Linux amd64, Gnome ENV.

I want to map the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Esc</kbd> (escape) in Arch Linux.
I run the command:

```
xmodmap -e 'clear Lock' -e 'keycode 0x42 = Escape'
```

It works well, but a moment later, the Caps Lock key works again.
And I must run the command again.

I'm pretty sure that this solution worked well maybe a year ago. What's my problem? Can anyone help me to map the Caps Lock key to
Escape key forever in my Arch Linux OS?

Answer (score 78):

Any of the following (in increasing order of complexity):

1. Use [`setxkbmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setxkbmap) to remap the key (does not require a daemon and is independent of your desktop environment or window manager). Don't forget to add the command before the `exec gnome-session` (or similar) line in your `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`:

   ```
    setxkbmap -option caps:escape
   ```

   `setxkbmap` can be found in package [extra/xorg-setxkbmap](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xorg-setxkbmap/).
2. `dconf-editor` → `org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options` → Add `caps:escape` to the aforementioned field.
3. `gnome-session-settings` → Startup Programs → Add → Name=Remap caps lock to escape, command=`setxkbmap -option caps:escape`
4. [Create a custom keyboard layout](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)

FYI, I obtained the XKB rule by [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)ping `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` for `caps` and `esc`.

Comment: Thanks for no. 2. I was looking for that info for ages. No I can set this on the command line via `gsettings org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options ['caps:none', 'numpad:pc', 'numpad:mac']`

Comment: Regarding no. 1: If you want to swap it rather than have two escape keys, you can run `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape`.

Answer (score 11):

## Xorg.conf

You can achieve this by editing the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf`.

Example file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard     "on"
        Option          "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option          "XkbModel"  "pc104"
        Option          "XkbOptions" "caps:swapescape"
EndSection
```

You can specify multiple XkbOptions, for example `caps:swapcaps,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp` for having esc and caps swapped but also allowing the X to be killed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. You can find more info about this in `man xkeyboard-config`.

## GUI

You can also use GNOME Tweak Tool (gnome-tweak-tool package).
Just click on `Typing` and then choose whatever you like from the `Ctrl position` menu (see image below).

[image]

Comment: respect for 00-keyboard.conf option

Answer (score 5):

For use in `X`, the Arch Wiki Gnome page has instructions for [modifying the keyboard with XkbOptions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME#Modify_Keyboard_with_XkbOptions):

> Using the dconf-editor, navigate to the key named org.gnome.desktop.input-sources.xkb-options and add desired XkbOptions (e.g. 'caps:swapescape') to the list.

In the console, you can create a [custom keymap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_Keyboard_Keys_in_Console) for the same effect. Create your personal keymap with the requisite changes for <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> at `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps/i386/qwerty/yourmap` then `tar` it and include a line in `/etc/vconsole.conf` to call it:

```
KEYMAP=yourmap
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use xmodmap. Put your `~/.Xmodmap`:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

(be sure at starting X will use your `~/.Xmodmap`)

Comment: When I put this in `~/.Xmodmap`, nothing happens :(

Comment: Put line `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` to your `~/.xinitrc`!

Comment: When I put this in `~/.Xmodmap` and then run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` I get errors: `xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:1:  bad remove modifier name 'lock=caps_lock', not allowed
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:2:  bad keysym target key symbol 'Escape=Caps_Lock'
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:3:  bad keysym target key symbol 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
xmodmap:  .Xmodmap:4:  bad add modifier name 'lock=caps_lock', not allowed
xmodmap:  4 errors encountered, aborting`

Comment: You'll need spaces around equal sign. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 3):

! I don't know why the answers above don't work. Here is a working one for me. In your ~/.Xmodmap

```
! 66 is the keycode of Caps_Lock
clear    Lock
keycode  66 = Escape
```

and then

```
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

I'm using Fedora and non-Gnome window manager. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The Arch repos now include two relevant [interception tools](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools):

- **[caps2esc](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc)** (tap=`esc`, hold=`ctrl`)
- **[dual-function-keys](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys)** (fully customizable tap/hold remappings)

---

### [caps2esc](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc) (tap=`esc`, hold=`ctrl`)

1. Install via `pacman` (if using another distro, [install for your distro](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc#installation) or [build from source](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc#building)):

   ```
   $ sudo pacman -S interception-caps2esc
   ```
2. Create `/etc/interception/udevmon.yaml` and optionally [specify the mode](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/caps2esc#execution). Here, `-m 1` specifies "minimal" mode:

   ```yaml
   - JOB: intercept -g $DEVNODE | caps2esc -m 1 | uinput -d $DEVNODE
     DEVICE:
       EVENTS:
         EV_KEY: [KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_ESC]
   ```
3. Enable and start `udevmon`:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl enable udevmon
   $ sudo systemctl start udevmon
   ```

---

### [dual-function-keys](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys) (customizable remappings)

1. Install via `pacman` (if using another distro, [install for your distro](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys#package-manager) or [build from source](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys#from-source)):

   ```
   $ sudo pacman -S interception-dual-function-keys
   ```
2. Create `/etc/interception/dual-function-keys/my-mappings.yaml`, e.g. to remap tap/hold actions for `caps` and `shift`:

   ```yaml
   MAPPINGS:
     - KEY: KEY_CAPSLOCK
       TAP: KEY_ESC
       HOLD: KEY_BACKSPACE
     - KEY: KEY_LEFTSHIFT
       TAP: KEY_ENTER
       HOLD: KEY_LEFTSHIFT
   ```
3. Create `/etc/interception/udevmon.yaml`:

   ```yaml
   - JOB: intercept -g $DEVNODE | dual-function-keys -c /etc/interception/dual-function-keys/my-mappings.yaml | uinput -d $DEVNODE
     DEVICE:
       EVENTS:
         EV_KEY: [KEY_CAPSLOCK, KEY_LEFTSHIFT]
   ```
4. Enable and start `udevmon`:

   ```
   $ sudo systemctl enable udevmon
   $ sudo systemctl start udevmon
   ```

Comment: can you use this so that instead of ctrl on hold, it does enter or backspace instead? My right pinky is weak, so it would be nice to give it a little break

Comment: @emilBeBri You can do something like that using dual-function-keys ([interception-dual-function-keys](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/interception-dual-function-keys/) in Arch), which is a more configurable version of caps2esc. I updated with an example of remapping `caps -> tap=esc, hold=backspace` and `shift -> tap=enter, hold=shift`

Comment: Note that not all combinations work, e.g. I couldn't get `hold=enter` to work although `tap=enter` worked.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` can also be auto-generated using `systemd-localed`. Use the following command:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us "" "" caps:escape
```

Or, including some other useful options:

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us,de "" "" caps:escape,grp:alt_caps_toggle,grp_led:caps,lv3:ralt_switch_multikey,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,eurosign:e,rupeesign:4
```

Quick explanations:

- <kbd>CapsLk</kbd> functions as <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Toggles between two keyboard layouts `us`/`de` with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLk</kbd>
- CapsLk **LED** indicates which layout is active
- Right Alt (<kbd>RAlt</kbd>) is the "multikey" (see [Compose Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key))

  - <kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> generates `€`
  - <kbd>RAlt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> generates `₹` (similar to how <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> generates `$`)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> kills X

Answer (score 1):

Another great option is https://github.com/maricn/interception-vimproved interception plugin.

It does Esc on tap, CTRL on hold, plus:

- Return becomes Right CTRL on hold
- Hold space to change the hjkl keys on the home row to arrow keys, b to backspace, d to delete and more

Answer (score 0):

To **swap** Caps Lock with Escape, you can use the following command:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape
```

Comment: This works under X11 only, not on Wayland