# Mapping capslock to printscreen key using setxkbmap

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, setxkbmap

I am trying to map my caps-lock key to the print-screen key. Looking up in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules` directory, and searching for `print`, `prnt` etc., I found out that the key is called one of

- prsc
- PrtSc

Now, following the steps mentioned [in this reply](https://superuser.com/a/568573/123710), I did:

```
➜ setxkbmap -option caps:prsc

➜ sudo setxkbmap -option caps:prsc
No protocol specified
Cannot open display ":0"

➜ setxkbmap -option caps:PrtSc
```

However, none of these worked. However, doing the same for `caps:escape` (as mentioned in the linked post above) works.

Is there some other mapping/binding that is needed before PrtSc key can be bound as well?

I am on Archlinux, using x11 (i3).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`xmodmap`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap):

```
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock" -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Print"
```

See `xmodmap -pke` to get the names of available functions like `Caps_Lock`, `Print`, or `XF86AudioMute`.